How to use `android.R.string` on android and custom strings on all other platforms
I have following use cases that I can't solve without a workaround.

// expect function
@Composable
expect fun stringOk() : String

// implementation for all but android
@Composable
actual fun stringOk() = stringResource(Res.string.ok)

// implementation for android
@Composable
actual fun stringOk() = stringResource(android.R.string.ok)

In this case I want to use android.R.string.ok on android and my custom resource on all other platforms. My solution is ok, but looks weird and does not allow me to use stringResource(Res.string...) through out my code but instead I must use my custom function.
Can I somehow "map" android.R.string.ok to my Res.string.ok string on android in a better way?
Note: android.R.string.ok is translated to probably all languages, my custom strings aren't and I don't want to repeat things for android but just keep the platform default translation on android.

I'm not sure what stops you from moving all the android translation files to shared code, that's what I would do. An other option is creating a script that will generate a huge when for you, from a list of your existing translation files, that shouldn't be hard to implement in any language - but I don't think there's some built in way of doing so

All the android.R.string stuff comes from the android source code - its not part of my own resources... that's the problem here. Otherwise, if they would be inside my code, I would simply move them to the compose common resources folder of course...

In the past I've used https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources to share my strings between all OS's.

@Robin I use their parcelable library but regarding the resource library I think it is obsolete as there has been added support for shared resources to compose recently anyways... And I can't see how moko should help reusing the android string from the android framework
